# Git inserting unicode characters after line normalization

Tags: git, unicode, tfs, mingw

This is a really weird situation, and I'm hoping someone can help. I'm using git in TFS 2015, and I've been trying to normalize the line endings in a repository.

**Background**

I've been trying various combinations of the following:

```
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
```

or

```
git rm --cached -r .
git add --all .
git commit -am "commit msg"
```

I've ran these commands quite a few times, whilst also playing around with the `git config --global core.autocrlf` setting. I've only tried `true` and `false` - I have not used `input`.

I've also been adding / removing and modifying my `.gitattributes` file whilst trying all of this.

**The Problem**

I noticed after my last commit, that some of the files in the repo now have every second line replaced with a ton of unicode characters. Observed in Notepad++ with "Show all characters" turned on:

[image: Unicode madness]

Note the CRs and LFs seem to be split across multiple lines, too - the "CR" lines are overwriting existing lines in the file.

Only the CRs and LFs disappear when I turn "Show all characters" off - everything else in the file is a physical character. The files also show up as "Encode in UCS-2 LE BOM" instead of "UTF-8 BOM" as I would expect:

[image: File Encoding]

**What I've Tried**

I looked for the commit that this happened on, but it doesn't exist. If I reset back to a commit that I KNOW had the original file content in it, nothing changes - no matter what commit I reset to, the files remain as-is.

Also to note, is that when I look at the file via the TFS UI, it looks fine:

[image: TFS]

And the commit history is as I would expect - the last commit being quite a few hours ago (this is the one I've been trying to reset to).

I can download the affected files via the download button on the TFS UI, and they look fine.

I tried to overwrite some of the downloaded files in my local repo - hoping I could sort it out with another commit, but git complains about line endings, and that the files aren't staged.

```
ME@MYMACHINE MINGW64 /d/git/CLIENT.Core.ProjectTemplates (feature/code-policies)
$ git st
On branch feature/code-policies
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature/code-policies'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   Powershell/TFS/templates/buildDefinitions/CLIENT/CLIENT.WCFService-CI.json

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

ME@MYMACHINE MINGW64 /d/git/CLIENT.Core.ProjectTemplates (feature/code-policies)
$ git commit -am "testing overwrite"
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Powershell/TFS/templates/buildDefinitions/CLIENT/CLIENT.WCFService-CI.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
On branch feature/code-policies
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature/code-policies'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

ME@MYMACHINE MINGW64 /d/git/CLIENT.Core.ProjectTemplates (feature/code-policies)
$ git st
On branch feature/code-policies
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature/code-policies'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   Powershell/TFS/templates/buildDefinitions/CLIENT/CLIENT.WCFService-CI.json

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Then, when I try to add the "modified" file, it just reports the following:

```
ME@MYMACHINE MINGW64 /d/git/CLIENT.Core.ProjectTemplates (feature/code-policies)
$ git add --all .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Powershell/TFS/templates/buildDefinitions/CLIENT/CLIENT.WCFService-CI.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

ME@MYMACHINE MINGW64 /d/git/CLIENT.Core.ProjectTemplates (feature/code-policies)
$ git st
On branch feature/code-policies
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature/code-policies'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Whilst this may work, the problem is that there are a lot of files and I don't really want to manually reconstruct the repo if I can help it!

I've also tried to entirely delete my repo and re-clone, but the files stay the same after the re-clone. I've tried to clone to a different location on my disk, too.

I've just tested cloning the repo on another machine too - and the same behaviour occurs there too - so it's definitely something to do with the remote.

Lastly, it's worth noting that these files exist in a branch called feature/code-policies. I've tried to branch off that branch to see if there's a problem with the branch itself, but it doesn't make any difference. I assume there's something corrupt in the branch itself?

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Does anyone have any idea what might be going on, and how I might be able to sort the problem out?

Comment: Do you and your collaborator make changes on different operating systems?

Comment: No, and that's nothing to do with the problem. The problem is that the encoding in a few of the files was set to "UCS-2 LE BOM" instead of UTF8, and at some point that encoding has seriously screwed up during a git commit, altering a file. I used the powershell "Out-File" cmdlet to output the affected files. Changing the encoding on the Out-File call stopped the files from being created with the dodgy encoding, but I still have no idea why they ended up so messed up.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're working on a Windows machine. [Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/), you can configure Global settings or Per-repository settings.

- **Global settings for line endings**

On Windows, you simply pass `true` to the configuration. For example:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
# Configure Git on Windows to properly handle line endings
```

- **Per-repository settings**

Optionally, you can configure the way Git manages line endings on a per-repository basis by configuring a special *.gitattributes* file. The *.gitattributes* file must be created in the root of the repository and committed like any other file.

Here's an example *.gitattributes* file. You can use it as a template for your repositories:

```
# Set the default behavior, in case people don't have core.autocrlf set.
* text=auto

# Explicitly declare text files you want to always be normalized and converted
# to native line endings on checkout.
*.c text
*.h text

# Declare files that will always have CRLF line endings on checkout.
*.sln text eol=crlf

# Denote all files that are truly binary and should not be modified.
*.png binary
*.jpg binary
```

- **Refreshing a repository after changing line endings**

Save your current files in Git, so that none of your work is lost.

```
git add . -u
git commit -m "Saving files before refreshing line endings"
```

Remove every file from Git's index.

```
git rm --cached -r .
```

Rewrite the Git index to pick up all the new line endings.

```
git reset --hard
```

Add all your changed files back, and prepare them for a commit. This is your chance to inspect which files, if any, were unchanged.

```
git add .
# It is perfectly safe to see a lot of messages here that read
# "warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in file."
```

Commit the changes to your repository.

```
git commit -m "Normalize all the line endings"
```

Check your steps to see whether they are correct.

Comment: Thanks - you are correct (I knew all this) but you have not attempted to address my problem at all (and there are a number of other SO answers that provide more detail to your answer). I was actually trying to normalize all line endings stored in the git repo to CRLF, as I could not control one of the clients' autocrlf settings (our TFS build agent). The TFS build reports the "Converting LF to CRLF" git warnings to STDERR during a powershell task, so I was trying to suppress the warning by converting everything to CRLF.